# Evitar repetir valor en option value en php

Tags: php

Buenos días, estoy trabajando con variables dentro de option value, pero no puedo evitar que salgan opciones repetidas, en la base de datos el campo caja la información que contiene se repite pero no se como poner que muestre solo una vez la información dentro del select y que se omitan las demás, muchas gracias.

```
<form role="form" name="caja" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="muestra_archivo.php" method="POST"> 

    <TR ALIGN=CENTER> 
        <th><label for="caja">Seleccionar caja: </label></th>
<?php
        $res1 = $mysqli->query($query);

?>   
<td><select name="caja">    
    <?php    
    while ( $rw = $res1->fetch_array() )    
    {   
        ?>  

        <option value="<?php echo $rw['caja']; ?>" >
        <?php echo $rw['caja']; ?>
        </option>

        <?php

    }  
    ?> 



</select>
</td>

<TD><input type="submit" value="Aceptar"></TD>
</form>
</TR>
</table>
```

Comment: Si en la base de datos el campo caja esta repetido y no quieres que no lo muestre varias veces, puedes modificar la consulta para que solo muestre una de cada "select distinct caja....", otra opcion es meter los elementos en un array y utilizar la función array_unique()

Comment: Estoy utilizando DISTINCT pero me ha dado resultado, voy a probar con array_unique y te aviso que resulto, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si lo estas utilizando y se repiten te pasara lo mismo con array_unique, revisa que no contengan espacio o que tengan algún carácter en mayúscula/minúscula de diferrencia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el

```
 select DISTINCT caja FROM anytable
```

Comment: Hey muchas gracias, ya funciono con Group By, gracias por su apoyo, saludos y bendiciones

Comment: @Stravos77 si esta respuesta resolvio tu problema es necesario que la marques con la palomita verde como respuesta correcta para que tu pregunta este como resuelta, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Quizas si haces un GroupBy en la consulta por el campo caja evistes la repeticion de este!

[image: Tabla]

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]